# Disable font scaling for UIAlertController text

Tags: ios, fonts, accessibility, uialertcontroller

In my own experience, I think we can not disable font scaling (**Accessibility**) for UIALertConterller's title, message, and other action buttons. I have gone through apple docs and other stack overflow threads to find the exact answer with yes or no. I know this is not a direct programming question but it would be a great help if someone has some inputs on this. A reference to apple doc stating 'we can not disable font scaling' will be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller)

> *The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.*

Comment: Agree with you, but as per apple doc it does not clear that what limitations it has in context of Accessibility

Comment: Well you can disable font scaling by only accessing the UILabel (title, message)  but you are not allowed to access them, so the answer is no you can't configure accessibility.

Unless you don't create custom Alert.

Comment: This question has some background from react-native and we will go ahead with no customization and use as it (default alert controller which is UIAlerController) provided by the react-native package. Thanks for your time